# how to start glmulti with consensus

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, glm

Given:

- use of R/Rstudio and the library "glmulti"
- we use "set seed" of 123465
- we use the Noam Ross data and tutorial for glmulti ([hyperlink](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/2/20/model-selection-drug.html))

Except that we make 5 "sub-runs" that use this code:

```
fish.model_N <- glmulti(global.model,
        level = 2,  #  just look at main effects
        method = "g",
        crit="aicc",
        report = TRUE,
        plotty = FALSE,
        popsize = 10,
        mutrate = 0.025,
        sexrate = 0.01,
        imm = 0.33,
        confsetsize = 3,
        deltaM = 10,
        deltaB = 0)
```

and instead of "N" we have the values 1...5 indicating which set it was.

**How do we combine them and use them for more glmulti?**

I want to do something like this:

1. have five random starts
2. Pick the best runs from them
3. use that as starting position for a larger run

Thoughts:

- It looks like "consensus" finds the better models from a list.
- if we put the output of consensus as an input, then 'glmulti' errors out saying "improper call of glmulti".

Clarification (as requested):

- Consensus can take several previous runs and find the "best" from
  those.
- A genetic algorithm builds on itself.  The "best" of previous
  iterations are "mutated" or "cross-mated" to create candidates for
  evaluation on the next iteration.
- Genetic models can be sensitive to initial conditions, and so having
  multiple start points for the searches can speed up the search.
- There doesn't seem to be a clean way to "inject" into the population,
  from consensus or another way.  That means we can't take 10 small
  runs but with different random IC and mutation paths and find the
  best, and use that as a "good seed" to start a larger run.

It might add quite a bit of extensibility to 'glmulti' if "new seeds" could be fed into the "live gene pool" for evaluation as it runs and if the "current best" could be popped out without stopping the run (much).

Comment: You have an error from "output of consensus as an input"? (That sounds fairly opaque to this non-user of that package.) Then why not post the code _and_ the error message?